# Add to cart returning error code 500

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to add a product to cart but response is http status code 500. How can i fix it?. I'm using a basic Craft Commerce template and just created some products.

Comment: When i enabled debug mode php shows me this:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getFieldLayout() on null in C:\Users\Vigan\Desktop\XAMPP_Subdomains\DevTest\craft\plugins\commerce\models\Commerce_OrderModel.php on line 192

Comment: The problem stands at orderssetting template it returns error on line 15     {% if orderSettings.id %}<input type="hidden" name="orderSettingsId" value="{{ orderSettings.id }}">{% endif %}

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleteing line 15 and 17 on orderssetting twig template, than updating entry on db with save button, than restoring twig template

Comment: Was this with the stock Commerce templates or were modifications made?  If you think you found a bug, can you submit details and steps to reproduce to support@craftcommerce.com?